# How to pass credentialID in the url in Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins

I am using this command:

```
sh 'git push https://${userid}:${passwd}@innersource.com/scm/raghu/demo.git'
```

But I want to use - credentialsId: 'f0079d43-9522-4133-9601-89c81f8ce7c9', instead of id and password and I want to pass credentialsId in the URL (https://innersource.com/scm/raghu/demo.git)

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **Credentials Binding Plugin** with `usernameColonPassword` property in your pipeline stage. This will also mask the credentials in console log as `****`.

```
stage(git-push) {
  withCredentials([usernameColonPassword(credentialsId: 'f0079d43-9522-4133-9601-89c81f8ce7c9', variable: 'USERPASS')]) {
    sh 'git push https://${USERPASS}@innersource.com/scm/raghu/demo.git'
  }
}
```

From the [documentation](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/credentials-binding/):

> `usernameColonPassword`
>   Sets a variable to the username and password given in the credentials, separated by a colon (:).

Answer (score 0):

```
environment {
    NEXUS_REPO = credentials('nexus-repo-credentials')
    GITHUB_AUTH_TOKEN = credentials('jx-release-version-github-token')
    GITHUB_REPO = 'demo'
}
```

in steps under stage, you can use

```
sh "git remote set-url origin git@github.com:innersource.com/scm/raghu/${GITHUB_REPO}.git"
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the answer: [Jenkins string interpolation with credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71196280/jenkins-string-interpolation-with-credentials)

You have to keep it in double quotes, but you need to escape the $ sign for the token (or any sensitive information).

```
sh "git push https://\${userid}:\${passwd}@innersource.com/scm/raghu/demo.git"
```