# How to pass credential id in curl command

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket, nexus

I am using below curl command to upload file in nexus.

curl -v -L -user "id":"password" --upload-file /jenkins/workspace/Raghu/SonarQube/target/spring-petclinic-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar https://uat.alm.com/nexus/content/repositories/NexusTest1_Snapshot/2.0/

I want to use credentials Id : "ff154118-e8d1-4c40-a63b-5ce5821c347c" instead of id and password.

Please help me how can i use it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass credentialID in the url in Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58597751/how-to-pass-credentialid-in-the-url-in-jenkins)

Comment: Look in the jenkins documentation for the withCredentials step. It has a very good documentation.

Comment: Could you please help me here - curl -v -L -user "id":"password" --upload-file /jenkins/workspace/Raghu/SonarQube/target/spring-petclinic-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar.  I want to pass credentials Id here instead of id and password.