# Jenkins string interpolation with credentials

Tags: jenkins, groovy, string-interpolation

I'm coding this function in Jenkins to query Artifactory:

```
def curlDockerArtifact(URL, registryName, moduleName, tag, token) {
 def controlURI = "${URL}/artifactory/api/storage/${registryName}/${moduleName}/${tag}"
 def result = sh(script: """
                         curl -I -H \'Authorization: Bearer $token\' \
                         https://$controlURI -o /dev/null -w \'%{http_code}\' -s
                         """, returnStdout: true)
}
```

But I get this warning which I'm tying to avoid.

```
Warning: A secret was passed to "sh" using Groovy string interpolation, which is insecure.
```

I tried using single quotes but the variables don't get correctly interpreted from Groovy. Any idea how to fix/refactor the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to keep double quotes like you do, but you need to escape the `$` sign for the token. Like this :

```
curl -I -H \'Authorization: Bearer \$token\'
```

The groovy will not interpolate the variable and the correct value will be passed on the shell level.

More informations : https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#interpolation-of-sensitive-environment-variables

Comment: Doesn't work. That way the token variable is always null.

Comment: so a second solution is to use triple singles quotes for the script, and don't escape the `$`.

Comment: Still not working.